# Does SharePoint on-premise have "preview" functionality for word, excel, and other files? How to enable?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, office-web-apps, 2019

Google isn't showing any good results, and a client has asked for the "preview" feature when you right click on a `.docx` file inside of SharePoint. I can see the feature on the SharePoint Online version, but not on the on-premise SharePoint 2019 solution.

Does this feature exist? Can it be enabled? If yes, what do I enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by deploying and configuring Office Online Server.
Details can be read here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server

Instructions are for SharePoint 2016 but applies for SharePoint 2019 as well.

Comment: Is this a change from how Sharepoint 2013 was ran? I have a client that shows me they have it working on their 2013 version without this additional server configured. There are also no alternatives, like simply having word + excel installed on the sharepoint app server? Double checking, thank you.

Comment: Office Online Server was originally called Office Web Apps. I believe it was possible to install this on the same server as SP2013 (but it was not officially supported). I do not know of any alternatives.